# Recursive method that searches an array doesn't work

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this recursive method that searches a 4x4 "board" for a word (think boggle except it only looks above, below, left, and right of the current letter). It gets passed an index (the current letter it is searching for from a given word), and the row and column to search around. The first `if` statement takes care of the first letter, and always works. The next `else if` statement doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated as to why. `secondArray` is used in another part of the program when it is displayed.

```
private boolean verifyWord(int index, int row, int column) {
    System.out.println(index + " " + row + " " +column);
    if (index == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < letterArray[0].length; i2++) {
                if (letterArray[i][i2] == wordToFind.charAt(index)) {
                    secondArray[i][i2] = true;
                    verifyWord(index+1, i, i2);
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (index > 0 && index < wordToFind.length()) {
        // check above row
        if (row+1 < row) {
            if (letterArray[row+1][column] == wordToFind.charAt(index)) {
                secondArray[row+1][column] = true;
                verifyWord(index+1, row+1, column);
            }
        }

        //check below row
        if (row-1 >= 0) {
            if (letterArray[row-1][column] == wordToFind.charAt(index)) {
                secondArray[row-1][column] = true;
                verifyWord(index+1, row-1, column);
            }
        }

        //check left column
        if (column-1 >= 0) {
            if (letterArray[row][column-1] == wordToFind.charAt(index)) {
                secondArray[row][column-1] = true;
                verifyWord(index+1, row, column-1);
            }
        }

        //check right column
        if (column+1 < letterArray[0].length) {
            if (letterArray[row][column+1] == wordToFind.charAt(index)) {
                secondArray[row][column+1] = true;
                verifyWord(index+1, row, column+1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        boolCheck = true;
    }
    return boolCheck;
}
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

The first condition `if(row+1 < row)` in your `else if(index > 0 && index < wordToFind.length())` would never be evaluated to `true` (*x+1* is always bigger than *x*).

You probably want it to be `if(row+1 < letterArray.length)`